# Recurring donation issue (Chartiable Plugin in wordpress )

Tags: php, wordpress, donations

I am using the Charitable plugin and the currency dropdown works fine. However, when I choose recurring payments, it always shows the currency as pounds, regardless of what I select

I want it to work the same as a normal donation, where whatever currency I have chosen should be visible.